# Graph-Aided Search Result filtering example

Tags: elasticsearch, neo4j, cypher, graphaware

I've duplicated the Movie database of `Neo4j` on `Elasticsearch` and it's indexed with the index `nodes`. It has two types `Movie` and `Person`. I am trying to make a simple `Result Filtering` with `Graph-Aided Search` using this curl command line:

```
curl -X GET localhost:9200/nodes/_search?pretty -d '{
   "query": {
      "match_all" : {}
   },

   "gas-filter": {
       "name": "SearchResultCypherfilter",
       "query": "MATCH (p:Person)-[ACTED_IN]->(m:Movie) WHERE p.name= 'Parker Posey' RETURN m.uuid as id",
       "ShouldExclude": true,
       "protocol": "bolt"
   }
}'
```

But I get as results all the 171 nodes of both types `Movie` and `Person` in my index `nodes`. However, as my query says I want to return only the type `Movie` by its title. So basically it doesn't look to the `gas-filter` part.

Also when I put `false` as the value of `shouldExclude` I am getting the same results.

**[UPDATE]**

I tried the suggestion of @Tezra, I am now returning only the id `uuid` and I put `shouldExclude` instead of `exclude` but still getting the same results.

I am working with:

- Elasticsearch 2.3.2
- graph-aided-search-2.3.2.0
- Neo4j-community 2.3.2.10
- graphaware-uuid-2.3.2.37.7
- graphaware-server-community-all-2.3.2.37
- graphaware-neo4j-to-elasticsearch-2.3.2.37.1

**Result that should be returning**:

The `uuid` of the movie titled `You've Got Mail`.

---

I tried to follow this [tutorial](https://github.com/graphaware/graph-aided-search#configuration) for the configuration, and I found out that `index.gas.enable` had the value `false` so I changed it and finished the configuration just like in the tutorial:

```
mac$ curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/nodes/_settings?index.gas.neo4j.hostname=http://localhost:7474
{"acknowledged":true}

mac$ curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/nodes/_settings?index.gas.enable=true
{"acknowledged":true}

mac$ curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/indexname/_settings?index.gas.neo4j.user=neo4j
{"acknowledged":true}

mac$ curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/indexname/_settings?index.gas.neo4j.password=mypassword
{"acknowledged":true}
```

After that I tried to add the settings of `boltHostname` and `bolt.secure` but it didn't work and I had this error:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Can't update non dynamic settings[[index.gas.neo4j.boltHostname]] for open indices [[nodes]]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Can't update non dynamic settings[[index.gas.neo4j.boltHostname]] for open indices [[nodes]]"},"status":400}
```

So I closed my index to configure it and then opened it again:

```
mac$ curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/nodes/_close
{"acknowledged":true}

mac$ curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/nodes/_settings?index.gas.neo4j.boltHostname=bolt://localhost:7687
{"acknowledged":true}

mac$ curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/nodes/_settings?index.gas.neo4j.bolt.secure=false
{"acknowledged":true}

mac$ curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/nodes/_open
{"acknowledged":true}
```

After finishing the configuration I tried again on `Postman` the same `gas-filter` query that I was executing with `curl` and now I am getting this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "runtime_exception",
        "reason": "Failed to parse a search response."
      }
    ],
    "type": "runtime_exception",
    "reason": "Failed to parse a search response.",
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "client_handler_exception",
      "reason": "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)",
      "caused_by": {
        "type": "connect_exception",
        "reason": "Connection refused (Connection refused)"
      }
    }
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

I don't know which connection the error is talking about. I am sure I passed the correct password of `Neo4j` in the configuration. I've even stopped and restarted again the servers of `Elasticsearch` and `Neo4j` but still the same errors.

The settings of my index `nodes` looks like this:

```
{
  "nodes" : {
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "gas" : {
          "enable" : "true",
          "neo4j" : {
            "hostname" : "http://localhost:7474",
            "password" : "neo4j.",
            "bolt" : {
              "secure" : "false"
            },
            "boltHostname" : "bolt://localhost:7687",
            "user" : "neo4j"
          }
        },
        "creation_date" : "1495531307760",
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "SdrmQKhXQmyGKHmOh_xhhA",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "2030299"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn't it be "shouldExclude" instead of "exclude"? Also, I think you need to return only m.id.

Comment: @Tezra even with `shouldExclude` instead of `exclude` I am getting the same results. And why should I return only m.id?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the `Connection refused` exception that I was getting was because of the `Wifi`. So I had to disconnect from the internet to make it work. I know it is not the perfect solution. So if anyone found a better way of doing it please share it here.